# Default string formats that will deserialise successfully to an Instant?

Tags: jackson

What string formats will deserialise successfully to an Instant type, using a vanilla object mapper?

I would like to follow Postels law and be as wide as possible in accepting serialised time formats, but my testers would like to know the range of possible date formats so they can test around it.

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by "vanilla"? By default `Jackson` treats `Java 8` time package like classic `POJO`-s. If you want to treat these classes like `time` and use formatting try to register [`JavaTimeModule`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime) and use `@JsonFormat` annotation together with `POJO`. Your question is not clear right now. Please create some examples what do you want to test and what result do you expect.

Comment: Thanks Michal for that. Wrote up some tests for this so I'll try and clarify soon..